# Halt scrolling momentum in iScroll 5

Tags: javascript, iscroll

When scrolling with momentum in iScroll 5, is there a way to interrupt the scroll, stopping it in its tracks?

I have attempted toggling the momentum option, and forcing another scrollTo but haven't quite found the behaviour I need.

Here are my failed attempts: http://jsfiddle.net/chvtmwz5/4/

```
// only comes into effect once scroll is finished:    
myScroll.options.momentum = false;

// halts scroll, but forces it back to the start unless we know the current scroll
myScroll.scrollTo(0,0);

// halts div scroll but allows scrollbar scroll animation to continue
var currentX = myScroll.x;
myScroll.scrollTo(currentX + 1, 0); // (scrolling to the current value of x has no effect)
```